# screen resolution

Tags: resolution, screen

I have just uploaded Ubuntu 14.04 to my Oracle VM v.4.3.12 running on Windows 7.
Problem: I cannot change the screen resolution. In the Ubuntu settings> screen display, it says "Built-in display" 640x480, and I am unable to change it. I have downloaded the latest guest extensions.

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions?

Comment: Thanks, problem fixed. I had uploaded Guest additions, but I had to do it again inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

you must install virtualbox guest additions using  graphical mode press right ctrl key+f if you are using another screen mode and choose 'devices' click on 'insert guest additions cd image ' you will get 1024*768
if not clear see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxBpm63744M)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the VMs settings may hold the key. Is it possible that the VMs settings have the resolution at 640x480?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, although I had uploaded Guest additions, I found I had to do it again inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7THS0sPKdg&feature=youtu.be) is more clear
don"t forget to press right ctrl key+f if you are using another screen mode